# Postgres - Inserting data from another table for one column only

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting the following query in Postgres 9.6.3

```
INSERT INTO join_table ("table_1_id", "table_2_id") VALUES
      (7, SELECT "id" from "table_2" where label='Foo Bar');
```

This throws `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" at character 94`

I have seen examples for nested selects inside of an insert statement work where only the things being selected are inserted. Is the above query even possible?

Comment: Why do you need to use double quotes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting parens around the sub-query:

```
INSERT INTO join_table ("table_1_id", "table_2_id") VALUES
      (7, (SELECT "id" from "table_2" where label='Foo Bar'));
```

Comment: Ahh I knew it would be something simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `insert . . . select`.  `values` is unnecessary:

```
INSERT INTO join_table (table_1_id, table_2_id)
    SELECT y, "id" 
    FROM "table_2" 
    WHERE label = 'Foo Bar';
```

This also allows you to insert multiple rows from the other table.